# xpath to select up the last td value of a html table

Tags: html, xpath

Is it possible to select the last td value of the building permits issued table automatically?
i mean each week another td value gets added to the already existing td of the table.
I want to write a xpath which will automatically select the last td value
for ex- last week  Week two of April was selected via xpath this week it is Week three of April which i had to change manually by changing the xpath.
Is it possible to automate it via xpath?

Project url is-http://www.clarkcountyohio.gov/index.aspx?NID=283
thanks.

Comment: basically, try `td[last()]`.

Comment: will it work??? its a fixed html table , all the td doesnt have any value/text, basically its empty. some of them have value, some doesn't.

Comment: Your question lacks any research effort on your own. Seeing that Joel actually even answered your question and your question is quite trivial, I downvoted your question. SO isn't the place to ask others to do **all** the work for you. Please put some effort into your questions as well (one thing would be to check for correct spelling, "I" is always writen as a capital letter...).

Comment: I am new in xpath, so asking for help. Sure I will keep your views in my mind including spelling errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this xpath:

```
//table[preceding-sibling::span[1][starts-with(., '2014')][@class='Subhead1']]//tr/td[a and following-sibling::*[name()='td'][.=" "][not(*)]]
```

it looks for a `td` node with a child `a` node and has a first following-sibling with a name `td` whose content is `&nbsp;` and do not have any child nodes.

Comment: can you provide a more elaborate ans by seeing the html table from the url i gave. @Joel

Comment: I have already seen the url that you gave that is why I have arrived at the answer. It seems that when a td is not yet populated, it's contents is only `&nbsp;`, when it is populated, it contains an `a` tag. Since the URL contains two tables (for 2013 and 2014), I have edited my answer.

Comment: its not selecting week three[4/18 pdf] of April month.. i have tried it in xpath finder of google chrome @Joel

Comment: I have updated again my answer, this time I checked it with chrome xpath finder. It seems that the web page should follow strict coding if you wish to automate things. Some nodes has `&nbsp;` on them together with `a` nodes. Some have none.

Comment: I think this is the easier one- //SPAN/TABLE[1]//a[last()]. But Thanks for your help

Comment: i do not think so, `TABLE` is not a child of `SPAN`